# One-sided significance test: essay - key question

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

For an essay on the one-sided significance test, I have considered the following structure:

First, generally describe the one-sided test (such as an introduction, setting up the hypotheses, decision rule), then describe the errors more accurately, then write an example and finally make a comparison between the two-sided significance test and the alternative test with the one-sided significance test.

Is that a good structure or could we improve it? The structure should be such that the level is always higher, it should be divided into three requirement areas.

In addition, I am looking for a key question. I thought something like, "How do we know how much we're wrong if we don't reject $H_0$?", and describe in the answer the probability of error? Or is that wrong? Or is that not suitable as a key question?

Comment: In practice, the probability that we make an error of the second kind (hypothesis false, but we don't reject it) usually cannot be determined. To calculate this probability, we need additional informations. Note that the probability of making an error of the second kind is typically large.

Comment: We can calculate these probabilities using conditional probabilities, or not? So that question is not appropriate for a key question, is it? @Peter

Comment: Usually, in exercises the true probability is given (often a binomial distribution is used). And then, the question about the probability of making an error of the second kind is perfectly valid. If we don't have any clue about the true probability distribution, we cannot reasonably estimate the probability to make an error of the second kind.

Comment: I am also unsure of the merit of the comparison between a two-sided and a one-sided test. But that is probably a matter of taste. It might give an insight to the stuff.

Comment: Ah ok, I see! What do you think of the structure I proposed? What key question would you suggest me? @Peter

Comment: The answer might depend on whether you are talking about a particular one-sided test, or about one-sided tests in general. If a particular test, an effective discussion might depend on whether it's, say a t-test about a population mean (symmetrical null distribution) or a chi-squared test about a population variance (null dist'n not symmetrical). Also, in some cases discussion of type II error (and power) are elementary and in some cases not. You say nothing about the audience for the essay. Class assignment or industrial setting. Proving _you_ know the stuff, or educating your audience?

Comment: A friend of mine is a student and asked me about what I suggest her for the structure, so it is a class assignment. It is aout one-sided tests in general. What do you mean about the strucure? And what key-question would you suggest? @BruceET

Comment: Would need to know what level course and what material covered recently. Guess main issue is to be able to put into coherent sentences what student has learned. // Wondering about ethics of providing too much structure for graded essay. Publisher mindless online multiple choice testing and Q&A sites have already corrupted value of take-home tests based on problems. Essays next?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a question about mathematics education or teaching, and not a question about mathematics.  There is a Math Education SE where this question would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the usual way to approach hypothesis-tests

- Formulation of the hypothesis $H_0$.
- Formulation of the alternative hypothesis $H_1$
- Choosing a maximum probability for the error of first kind  denoted $\alpha$
- Choosing a critical range $B$ with the property that an occurence in $B$ has probability at most $\alpha$ assuming $H_0$ is true.
- Deciding whether the observed value lies in $B$. If it is, we assume $H_1$. If it is not, we have no reason to reject $H_0$.

As a key-question the probability to make an error of the second kind is a good one, but the exact probability distribution should be given so that the probability can actually be calculated.

Another possibility for a key question : Would it affect the decision, if we used a two-sided test rather than a one-sided-test ?

Comment: So, you mean that the essay should look like that: We describe the procedure, i.e. each step that we have to follow, or have I understood that wrong? Using the question: "Would it affect the decision, if we used a two-sided test rather than a one-sided-test ?" does it mean that we have to make a comparison between the one-sided and the two-sides test?

Comment: I just meant the question, whether the decision comes to another result, but for the rest of your comment. Yes, I think this is best.

Comment: Ah ok. We would get the same result with both (one-sided, two-sided) test, wouldn't we? How could we justify that?

Comment: I am looking again at the questions "How do we know how much we're wrong if we don't reject $H_0$" or "How do we know how much we're wrong if we reject $H_0$". How much we are wrong is given by the probability of error? Or do we know just how probable it is to reject or accept wrongly the assumption?

Comment: @MaryStar Usually the test is designed that $(1)$ assuming , $H_0$ is true, the probability that we reject $H_0$ is very small (at most $\alpha$, which is usually $1,2$ or $5$ %).Hence, we rarely make an error of the first kind. $(2)$ If $H_0$ is false , the probability that we don't  reject it, depends on "How false" $H_0$ is. If the true distribution is "far" from the assumed distribution, the probability to make an error of the second kind, will be small. But if it is "close" to the assumed distribution, we can have a high probability to make an error of the second kind.